# CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', 'editor2', {

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

http://gw.ablueman.co.uk/tabbednotepad.php

I have 3 ckeditor textareas, all three are the same but fairly different from the main one or the class.

If I put 3 replaces, it works fine. however if I try to use CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', 'editor2', 'editor3' {

It works, replacing them, but ignores anything after the { almost like the class.

Am I just formatting CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', 'editor2', {}); incorrectly, I need all three to use the same replace.

Heres the code:

```
<form name="title" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor3" name="editor3" rows="200"><?php echo $editor3;?></textarea>
<input id="tabtitle1" name="tabtitle1" size="30" placeholder="Tab Title.." />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    height: '600px',
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR, 
    toolbar:    
[   { name: 'document', groups: [ 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl' ] },        '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] }, { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe', 'Syntaxhighlight' ] }, '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'mode' ], items: [ 'Source', 'searchCode', 'autoFormat', 'CommentSelectedRange', 'UncommentSelectedRange', 'AutoComplete', '-', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
]});    
</script>
```

[EDIT] Just FYI, I tried CKEDITOR.replace( ['editor1', 'editor2'],
this didnt work either.

Comment: See how it is done here: http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/tabindex.html (the page contains 3 different instances on the same page, not in tabs like yours, but the idea is the same).

Comment: Nope that uses the class. You cant easily edit the class so that wont actually solve the problem. That's why I need to use CKEDITOR.replace rather than the class. Unless there is an easy way you know of using the ckeditor class to also change the toolbars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array of textarea id an call a CKEDITOR.replace with jquery and foreach. For example:

```
 var areas = Array('editor1', 'editor2', 'editor3');
    $.each(areas, function (i, area) {
     CKEDITOR.replace(area, {
      customConfig: '/Scripts/ckeditor/config.mini.js'
     });
    });
```

Comment: Will give this a go tomorrow when I get a chance, thanks for the update.

Comment: Ps. I turned to the dark side and im now using tinymce. Its soooo much better in my opinion. The documentation and implimentation just seems better to me.

Comment: This assumes and uses jQuery where it is not needed ; index-iterating the array is not longer, nor is ES6 `for..of`. jQuery is a performance burden in cases like thes.

Comment: @ElementW: CKEditor requires jQuery, so it is not an additional burden to use it as in this post.

Comment: @Stefan While it does not incur a dependency overhead as CKEditor requires it, it does incur a time overhead, as `$.each` [is not exactly a zero-cost abstraction](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/core.js#L243) ; while not improving readability over native constructs. I'm wrong on the "assume" part of my comment, though.

Comment: @ElementW: This guy talks about 3 editors in his page. Will need an electron microscope to notice a 'performance burden' here. I wonder how many editors are needed on the page before the 'burden' is a mountain and not a mole-hill?  Personally I see no problem with the readability of '.each' versus 'for', actually I think it might be simpler and easier on the eye to read '$.each(list, function(i, v)...' versus 'for(var i=0,i < list.length;i++)...' Not as simple as 'for (x in obj)' I'll grant you. For more complex manips you can reduce relative complexity even more using jQuery chaining.

Answer (score 9):

Ckeditor 4 allows you to replace multiple textareas with editors based on classname:

```
CKEDITOR.replaceAll('className');
```

[docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call CKEDITOR.replace with several ids at the same time.

[Its definition](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.replace) states that the first parameter is the ID or the element and the second one the configuration options.

Comment: Seems your right, shame really, I overcame this by having the <script> part in a separate file and just including it 3 times whilst feeding the name in by a variable.

Thanks for the answer though ;)

Comment: The odd things is if you put CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', 'editor2', 'editor3', it will replace editor 1,2,3. But it then ignores the configuration for them.